# Why doesn't clang -Wunused-member-function warn about an unused member function?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

I'm compiling a very basic program attempting to trigger output from `-Wunused-member-function`.

**test.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "Called foo" << std::endl; }
    void foo_unused() { std::cout << "Unused foo" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A obj;
    obj.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the following command

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wunused -Wunused-member-function \
        -Wunused-function -Wunneeded-member-function \
        test.cpp -o test
```

unfortunately contained not even a single warning. I expected the compiler to warn about `foo_unused` not being used.

Is there a different behavior I'm missing here? Otherwise, why doesn't clang complain about the unused member function?

Comment: Cause it's public? Try making it private

Comment: if you make `void foo_unused()` private - it will work as expected. Since `foo_unused` is public class member (type interface) there is nothing wrong with this. Compiler/linker will simply remove it when doing `dead code elimination`  optimization.

Comment: The problem is that public method can be used from anywhere. So there is no way to check that in one compilation unit. It would need to be done at the link stage, not compilation stage.

Comment: @Adam According to a C++ when you defining a class (struct, union) - you defining a type, not an object of this type ( like `A obj;`). So according to the C++ language A class is completely correct, because nothing wrong the type A.

Comment: @VictorGubin, no, private doesn't change anything: https://godbolt.org/z/TM8GdYbe8

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the class in an anonymous namespace to make the warning appear:

```
namespace
{
class A {
    public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "Called foo" << std::endl; }
    void foo_unused() { std::cout << "Unused foo" << std::endl; }
};
}
```

You can see that now you have the warning: https://godbolt.org/z/15Buo-

The reason is that this version can activate clang checks on public methods as well, as you explicitely said that this class will not be accessible in another translation unit.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works. I wonder if there's a way to check that for a big project at the link stage.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this available. At least nothing I know of :(

Comment: @Adam Linker will not include unused code into binary in any case off cause if you class is not a part of shared library/DLL. And if you enable full program optimization i.e. LTO, linker will warn you.

Comment: I understand, but I also want to remove unused functions from my code, and hence I want to see the actual unused functions in my project.

Comment: @VictorGubin I've tried enabling LTO and adding every possible warning flag but no warning shows up.